Proving $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$ from $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$
Problem: Using identity axioms, prove $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$ from $\forall x\forall y \, x=y$.
So far: I'm quite stuck on where to even begin. Working backward, I know we want $P(x)$ and $\exists xP(x)$, but I can't quite see how to write it down. I'm used to proof trees over Fitch-style proofs.

I'm not sure what you mean by "$\exists P(x)$".  What inference rule do you have to introduce "$\forall$"?

We can deduce $\forall x A$ from $A$ if the variable $x$ does not occur free in any uneliminated assumption in the deduction of $A$.

The idea is, obviously, to suppose $\exists x P(x)$ and try to deduce $\forall x P(x)$ going top-down.
From $\exists x P(x)$ you can apply the rule $\exists_\text{elim}$ and suppose $P(y)$ for an arbitrary $y$.
The delicate point is that, in natural deduction, to prove $\forall x P(x)$ as a conclusion of the rule $\forall_\text{intro}$, you should prove $P(x)$ for a variable $x$ that does not occur free in any undischarged assumption.
This means that from the assumption $P(y)$ you cannot apply directly the rule $\forall_\text{intro}$ since $y$ occurs free in that assumption.
Luckily, thanks to the hypothesis $\forall x \forall y \, x = y$, you can derive $P(x)$ with $x \neq y$ from $P(y)$. And now you can apply the rule $\forall_\text{intro}$ to $P(x)$ since $x$ does not occur free in any assumption.
The intuitive explanation above can be formalized in a natural deduction derivation as follows.
\begin{align}
\dfrac
{\displaystyle{ { {{} \atop {}} \atop {}} \atop [\exists x P(x)]^\bullet}
 \qquad
 \dfrac
 {\displaystyle{ \atop [P(y)]^*} \qquad \dfrac{\forall x \forall y \, x = y}{x = y}\forall_\text{elim}\times 2}
 {\dfrac{P(x)}{\forall x P(x)}\forall_\text{intro}}=
}
{\dfrac{\forall x P(x)}{\exists x P(x) \to \forall x P(x)}\to_\text{intro}^\bullet}
\exists_\text{elim}^*
\end{align}

It would be something like this:

$\forall x \forall y(x=y)$
| $\exists x P(x)$
| | $P(a)$
| | $\forall y(a=y)$ . . . . $1, \forall E$
| | $a=b$ . . . . . . . . $4, \forall E$
| | $P(b)$ . . . . . . . . . $3,5$
| $P(b)$ . . . . . . . . . . $3-6, \exists E$
| $\forall x P(x)$ . . . . . . . $7, \forall I$
$\exists x P(x) \to \forall xP(x)$ . . .$2-8, \to\!\!I$


Making the domain of discourse $D$ explicit in this question may simplify matters:


Plain text version:
1   ALL(x):ALL(y):[D(x) & D(y) => x=y]
Axiom
2   EXIST(x):[D(x) & P(x)]
    Premise

3   D(a) & P(a)
    E Spec, 2

4   D(a)
    Split, 3

5   P(a)
    Split, 3

    6   D(b)
        Premise

    7   ALL(y):[D(a) & D(y) => a=y]
        U Spec, 1

    8   D(a) & D(b) => a=b
        U Spec, 7

    9   D(a) & D(b)
        Join, 4, 6

    10  a=b
        Detach, 8, 9

    11  P(b)
        Substitute, 10, 5

12  ALL(x):[D(x) => P(x)]
    Conclusion, 6

13  EXIST(x):[D(x) & P(x)] => ALL(x):[D(x) => P(x)]
    Conclusion, 2

